# How to call a method in WSDL from Salesforce callout

Tags: salesforce, callouts

I m a new bie to the salesforce, and I m trying to get the response by calling a wsdl file from the salesforce.
I dont know how to call a method of the WSDL from HTTP callouts

The code is something Like this :-

//HTTP request
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('domain.com/webservices/wwservice.php?wsdl');
req.setMethod('GET');

ANd I m calling the HTTP request  and response  from the TestMethod.
The result I m getting is System.HttpResponse[Status=null, StatusCode=0] .

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the WSDL to your local machine, then upload the WSDL to Salesforce.com (Apex-->Generate from WSDL). This will generate the Apex classes needed to actually call web services described in the WSDL.

Anyway, it's all described here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm